# Devise: Show error when the user is already confirmed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I would like to show a error message when a confirmed user tries to resend confirmation. Is this something that is already provided by devise or should i have to override some of their methods? If so which methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by overriding create action of confimations controller

```
def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      flash[:notice] = "Confirmed already, Please try signing in" if resource.confirmed?
      respond_with({}, :location => after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end
```

I am just overriding the flash notice in the case of confirmed user

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to decide is if you really want to put a message for confirmed users. This might allow user enumeration (i.e have a robot try to find the users' email on your site... that's why there's the [paranoid mode](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Using-paranoid-mode,-avoid-user-enumeration-on-registerable).

If you truly want to display a confirmation message, you do not need to override the controller. Your user will already have an error in the resource something like: "was already confirmed, please try signing in".  You therefore don't need to modify the flash for this, you might simply want to use devise_error_messages! (or your own custom code to display error content).

Hope this helps.